# What is the exact difference between Task.ContinueWith and ActionBlock.LinkTo?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, .net-4.5, tpl-dataflow

I am new to TPL Dataflow `ActionBlock`, `TransformBlock` etc. I used to practice `Task.ContinueWith()` to create a pipeline if needed. I recently started practicing about the TPL Dataflow and its blocks.

But I am a bit confused about the exact difference between those two. So could you please advise me when to use what?

Answer (score 2):

These are two separate methods that have similar behavior but really don't relate to one another. `ContinueWith` schedules a continuation for a `Task`. With `async/await` you should not really need to use `ContinueWith` since the `async/await` keywords already schedule the remainder of your method as continuation. For example the two methods `AsyncAwait` and `Continuation` produce the same result.

```
public async Task AsyncAwait()
{
    await DoAsync();
    DoSomethingElse();
}

public async Task Continuation()
{
    await DoAsync().ContinueWith(_ => DoSomethingElse());
}

public Task DoAsync() => Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));

public void DoSomethingElse()
{
    //More Work
}
```

`LinkTo` on the other hand creates a disposable link between two `Tpl-Dataflow` blocks. That link can be configured in a number of ways [see DatflowLinkOptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowlinkoptions(v=vs.110).aspx). One of the most configuration items is to `PropagateCompletion`. As you can hopefully see a dataflow link can be much more than simple continuation. You can pass completion, add a predicate to filter data or even link blocks into a complex structure like a mesh or feedback loop. Also, dataflow links allow you setup "backpressure" to throttle a flow. If the downstream block becomes overloaded and it's input buffer fills the upstream blocks can pause processing. The complete behavior of a dataflow link is not easily implemented with continuations by hand.

```
public ITargetBlock<int> BuildPipeline()
{
    var block1 = new TransformBlock<int, int>(x => x);
    var block2 = new ActionBlock<int>(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
    block1.LinkTo(block2 , new DataflowLinkOptions() { PropagateCompletion = true });
    return block1;
}
```

Unless you're doing complex linking you should always prefer the use of `async/await` over raw continuations. `async/await` makes the code easier to write, understand and maintain. `LinkTo` only applies to dataflow blocks and should be viewed as something separate from continuations and used to construct dataflow networks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer